# How to process data using ajax, if there are thousand entries?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have 1000 entries of users with their email id. I want to send mail to all of them. But I want to do it with ajax.

**userdata.php**

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","namename","123456","namename");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }else{
     echo "Successfully Connected";
  }


  $selectsql = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
  $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con,$selectsql));
  $result = $con->query($selectsql);

 ?>
  <div>
    <div><h1>Send Mail</h1></div>
    <div>
        <p>Total Subscribers: <?php echo $rowcount; ?></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <table>
    <?php
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td> Email ID </td>"; 
                echo "<td>".$row["email"]."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
    ?>
    </table>
  </div>
```

It returns 1000 emails. Now I want to send these emails one by one to another page (Mail.php).

I know we can do this with ajax. But how? will it increase server load?

Please guide me through it. I want to know what logic I should use to send that much data to another page via ajax without increasing too much load on the server.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Why do you want to send all that emails to the browser and then back again? They are already there, and since you wanna use _all of them_, just use them as they come from db.

Comment: Ideally, this should be a script that needs to be executed on the server and not on the web. Use `cron` to schedule and send emails batch-wise.

Comment: @jeff but it will increase the load on the server if the data fetch from the server is 1000 or 5000 or greater. I tried to send mail at the time I fetch data from the server, but it stops working and my server can't handle that much data processing at one time.

Comment: then seperate it into chunks, or increase script execution time.

Answer (score 0):

In a single ajax call, send all the email ids so that you won't have 1000 calls to Mail.php.

Then in Mail.php, parse the request and extract all email ids and send mails by iterating all email idsin loop.